# Data inside app.get() isnt updated even if outside it updates

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the latest added data from firebase and send it to client here is my code

```js
onChildAdded(query(ref(config.db, "users/1/messages"), limitToLast(1)), (snapshot) => {
  console.log(snapshot.val()) //suppose this is line 1

    app.get("/rest", (req, res) => {
    console.log(snapshot.val()) // this is line 2
    res.json(snapshot.val());
  });
})
```

here after i add a child to the database `console.log(snapshot.val())` of line 1 prints the updated data but `console.log(snapshot.val())` from line 2 just prints the value that was the last one until new childs were added

can someone explain why this is happening and help solve this???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `app.get("/rest", callback)` for a second time doesn't remove the old callback, instead adding the new callback to the list of callbacks attached to that endpoint. In your current code, you create a new callback and connect it to that endpoint for each snapshot update that comes in; and because your oldest callback never calls `next()`, the data referenced by the oldest callback is what is returned.

If you want `/rest` to always return the latest version of the data, you should redefine the callback so that it returns the latest data in its first (and only) callback that reads the data from a shared reference to it.

```
// holds the reference to the latest data snapshot
let latestSnapshot = null;

// attaches the listener to keep latestSnapshot updated
onChildAdded(
  query(
    ref(config.db, "users/1/messages"),
    limitToLast(1)
  ),
  (snapshot) => {
    console.log("Data was updated!", snapshot.val());
    latestSnapshot = snapshot;
  }
);

// returns the data contained in latestSnapshot whenever requested
app.get("/rest", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Data was requested!", latestSnapshot.val());
  res.json(latestSnapshot.val());
});
```